# Running total using over clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I'm running SQL Server 2008, I'm currently trying to understand the over clause more, I've used it before but just with `row_number()` and I learned you can use aggregate functions with it and create things like a running total.

I created the following test database.

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
    employee nvarchar(50),
    sales decimal(18, 2),
    datesale datetime
);

Insert into sales Values('John','54.23','2017-01-30 08:00:00.000')
Insert into sales Values('John','123.96','2017-01-30 09:00:00.000')
Insert into sales Values('John','534.20','2017-01-30 10:00:00.000')
Insert into sales Values('Ben','98.34','2017-01-29 04:00:00.000')
Insert into sales Values('Ben','126.32','2017-01-29 05:00:00.000')
```

And used the following query to create a running sum for each employee

```
select 
    employee, sales, datesale, 
    SUM(sales) over (partition by employee order by datesale) as mvgsum 
from sales
```

On SQL Fiddle using SQL Server 2008 I get the following results

```
 | employee |  sales |                  datesale | mvgsum |
 |----------|--------|---------------------------|--------|
 |      Ben |  98.34 | January, 29 2017 04:00:00 |  98.34 |
 |      Ben | 126.32 | January, 29 2017 05:00:00 | 224.66 |
 |     John |  54.23 | January, 30 2017 08:00:00 |  54.23 |
 |     John | 123.96 | January, 30 2017 09:00:00 | 178.19 |
 |     John |  534.2 | January, 30 2017 10:00:00 | 712.39 |
```

However, in SQL Server Management Studio, on a SQL Server 2008 database, I get the following error using the same query, with the same table structure and data.

> Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

What could be causing this?

Comment: ,I'm Using 2014,it is also this query working fine.

Comment: Aggregade over clause introduced in 2012. It wont work on 2008. I faced similar thing when working with 2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SUM() OVER()` is not supported in SQL Server 2008.

You could use a correlated subquery:

```
select employee,
    sales,
    datesale,
    (
        select sum(sales)
        from sales s2
        where s1.employee = s2.employee
            and s2.datesale <= s1.datesale
        ) mvgsum
from sales s1
```

Or `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select employee,
    sales,
    datesale,
    x.mvgsum
from sales s1
cross apply (
    select sum(sales) mvgsum
    from sales s2
    where s1.employee = s2.employee
        and s2.datesale <= s1.datesale
    ) x
```